# Retrofit2 always runs on failure in fragment

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

**I am trying to hit api locally but onResponse method is not workingonFailure mehtod always runs**

```
class Categories : Fragment() {      
    lateinit var categories_recycler: RecyclerView      
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,  
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {      
        val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false)       
        categories_recycler = v.findViewById(R.id.categories_recycler)      
        categories_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)      
        categories_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)      
        retrofit()       
        return v          
    }  
    fun retrofit(){      
        val retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.instance     
        val client = retrofit.create(SkillClientRetrofit::class.java)    
        val call = client.CategoryNames()    
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<    List<  GetCatName>> {  
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<  List<  GetCatName>>, response: Response<  List<  GetCatName>>) {    
                if(response.isSuccessful) {  
                    activity.toast("this is success")  
                    val data = response.body()  
                    categories_recycler.adapter = CategoriesSkillAdapter(data!!)  
                }  
            }  
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<  List<  GetCatName>>, t: Throwable) {  
                activity.toast("this is error")  
            }  
        })  
    }  
}
```

**Below is RetrofitBuilder:**

```
object RetrofitBuilder {  
    private var r: Retrofit? = null  
    val instance:Retrofit  
        get(){  
            if(r == null){  
                r = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("<http://192.168.56.1:3000/>")  
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())  
                        .build()  
            }  
            return r!!  
        }  
}
```

Below is interface:

```
public interface SkillClientRetrofit
{ @GET(" category/names") fun CategoryNames(): Call< List< GetCatName>> }
```

Here is data class:

```
data class GetCatName( 
    @SerializedName("_id") val id: String,
    @SerializedName("category_name") val categoryName: String )
```

Comment: Below is interface:

Comment: public interface SkillClientRetrofit{    
    @GET("  category/names")    
    fun CategoryNames(): Call<  List<  GetCatName>>      
}

Comment: **Here is data class:**

Comment: data class GetCatName(       
    @SerializedName("_id") val id: String,        
    @SerializedName("category_name") val categoryName: String    
)

Comment: What does the exception in onFailure say?

Comment: nothing says. when i launch activity on android phone. onFailure always show toast @UmangBurman

Comment: In toast write: t.message then you can see what the error is.. post here

Comment: toast showing this eror:  java.net.socketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1:3000

Comment: Are you using WAMP?

Comment: You should always include relevant details in your question rather than leaving them in comments. You can edit your own question at any time! Also, make use of the code formatting facilities; they make everything much easier to read.